# How does DOM API affect HTML parsing?

Tags: html, dom, web-performance

During reading how the DOM tree is created [HTML5 spec: 8.2.1 Overview of the parsing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#overview-of-the-parsing-model), a question came into my mind and I could not find the answer.

According to the spec using `document.write` is bad and apart from other issues, it will pause parsing and supply new characters into tokenizer input.

The question is how does it look like when one use DOM API, eg. `appendChild`. When will it be executed?

As far as I understand, this will add already created `Node` so the parsing and tokenization is not needed. However does the new node will be attached immediately or after constructing the "first/original" DOM tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens immediately, to the DOM in what ever state it is in at the time. The DOM document always forms a consistent tree, so it can always be added to safely.

Appending elements has always been pretty harmless in that respect, but removing elements from the DOM document while parsing was ongoing, used to be a good way to crash older IE versions. In fact, that problem continued to some degree right up until IE implemented the HTML5 parsing algorithm in IE10.

Comment: Thanks, could you provide a link to the source?

Comment: No, but it's easily testable. For example, put this script in the middle of your source `<script>console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("*").length);
document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("meta"));
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("*").length);</script>` and you'll see that the number of elements in the DOM document increases by one, and that subsequent parsed mark up increases the element count further.

Comment: Fair point. Just wondering what if the script is async. However, since the HTML parsing is paused during JS execution one can expect that changes will be reflected without any delay.

Comment: Indeed. Whether a script is async, or deferred, does not change matters. That is, when a script executes, and appendChild is called, the DOM will be updated immediately. What the async and defer attributes change is when the script as a whole will be executed.